# How do I pull an image from an RSS feed wrapped in media:content tag?

Tags: php, rss, media

I am assembling a simple news aggregator. When attempting to pull images from the feed, I have run into an issue when trying to get the image.

```
  foreach($xml->channel->xpath('//item') as $xml_item){ // fetch all <item> tags from the XML
    $feed_item = false;
    $feed_item['title']     = strip_tags(trim($xml_item->title));
    $feed_item['description']   = strip_tags(trim($xml_item->description));
    $feed_item['link']      = strip_tags(trim($xml_item->link));
    $feed_item['date']      = strtotime($xml_item->pubDate);
    $feed_item['source']    = $source_name;
    $feed_item['url']           = (string)$xml_item->enclosure['url'];
    $feed[] = $feed_item;
  }
  return $feed;
}
```

```
foreach ($feed as $feed_item => $item) {
 
  $time = date('m/d/Y', $item['date']);
  $serverDate = date('m/d/Y');

  $title = shorten_text($item['title'], $MAX_TITLE_LENGTH);
  $text = shorten_text($item['description'], $MAX_TEXT_LENGTH);
  
  //display news if it is from today
  if ($time == $serverDate){
  echo <<<END
<a href="$item[link]" target="_blank"><h3>$title</h3></a><br />
<img src="$item[url]" width="200" height="150" /><br />
<small><b>$item[source]</b> :: $time</small><br />
$text</a><hr />
END;
}
    
  else{
        //do nothing
  }
}
```

This works well. The information is pulled as expected. The only problem is, SOME of my feeds have the image in a tag such as

```
<media:content url="https://static.independent.co.uk/2022/12/15/00/urnpublicidap.orgdf360a33b44149d48e1180b1afcaa1e6.jpg?width=1200&auto=webp" type="image/jpeg" medium="image">
```

my code will only pull an image from xml formatted like this

```
<enclosure length="0" type="image/jpeg" url="https://img.huffingtonpost.com/asset/639a50982300005d00e651cd.jpeg?cache=hnvl9kyal3&ops=224_126"/>
```

I simply do not know how to pull the url from the media:content tag

I have tried to more or less copy my line

```
$feed_item['url']           = (string)$xml_item->enclosure['url'];
```

in every way I could think of. Php is new to me, while coding is more of an old hat I'm attempting to put on again. I'm not sure how to phrase my question to a search engine in a way to bring up what i'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Based simply upon the cited url that originates at `static.independent.co.uk` perhaps the following small example might help. The key thing is to use the namespace and to do so you must register that with the XPath object. It is is not particularly clear what library you are using to parse the XML/RSS feed - the following uses the vanilla `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`

The appropriate namespace can either be found by manually inspecting the RSS/XML and matching the `media` to it's corresponding uri or you can programmatically add all namespaces though that is a little more involved so is shown after the main example.

```
$url='https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/rss';

libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->load( $url );
libxml_clear_errors();

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$xp->registerNameSpace('media','http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

$expr='//channel/item';
$col=$xp->query($expr);

if( $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $node ){
        $expr='media:content';
        $content=$xp->query( $expr, $node );
        if( $content && $content->length > 0 )echo $content->item(0)->getAttribute('url') . '<br />';
    }
}
```

To programmatically set all the namespaces found you query the document for namespaces and iterate through the collection, like so:

```
$expr='namespace::*';
$col=$xp->query( $expr );
if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $index => $node ){
        $xp->registerNameSpace( $node->localName, $node->nodeValue );
    }
}
```

The above example yields content like this ( lots more than this )

```
https://static.independent.co.uk/2022/12/15/10/915b33b33d1fbc188136a643adca671cY29udGVudHNlYXJjaGFwaSwxNjcxMTg0MjUw-2.70259339.jpg?width=1200&auto=webp
https://static.independent.co.uk/2022/12/15/10/newFile-3.jpg?width=1200&auto=webp
https://static.independent.co.uk/2022/12/15/10/efd36497014efc26235afa218cf725fbY29udGVudHNlYXJjaGFwaSwxNjcxMTg1NDA3-2.70259329.jpg?width=1200&auto=webp
https://static.independent.co.uk/2022/12/14/14/7ffcb88d09bb14563071e5641032f90cY29udGVudHNlYXJjaGFwaSwxNjcxMTEzMzEy-2.70206703.jpg?width=1200&auto=webp
https://static.independent.co.uk/2022/12/15/10/afa021056131ded1adb16fea9971da7bY29udGVudHNlYXJjaGFwaSwxNjcxMTgwOTEy-2.70258774.jpg?width=1200&auto=webp
```

Other libraries, SimpleXML etc, offer their own methods for binding namespaces but can offer no guidance as [a] I don't use them [b] I don't know what you are using.

Comment: thank you for the push in the right direction. As for the library I am using, I should have clarified that I am not using one. it honestly hadn't occurred to me.. full code here: https://codefile.io/f/mQ9sZjeZgW7j9i6RqsZO

Comment: Ok - it's the `simplexml` api that you are using and I'm sure that has the facility to work with namespaces but I've never used it so I cannot offer guidance.